# Hide/Show Header as a Scroll Function

Tags: jquery, header, scroll, hide, show

community :). I'm trying to Hide or Show the Header DIV depending on wether the user has scrolled down (Hide Header) or up (Show header). I'm basically trying to achieve this result: http://codepen.io/AdobeWordPress/pen/tigrx

So far, the closest I've been able to get to it is with the following code:

```
var scroll_pos = 0;
var scroll_time;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout(scroll_time);
    var current_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (current_scroll >= 0) {
        if (current_scroll <= scroll_pos) {
            $('.cs_mega_menu').slideDown('230');
        }
        else {
            $('.cs_mega_menu').slideUp('230');
        }
    }

    scroll_time = setTimeout(function() {
        scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    }, 100);
});
```

But, the problem is that the effect is inexact (Does not respond properly every time) and the animation is not fluid.

When I try to use the code from the codepen example, my website goes blank no matter what I do :/. If you could help me to transcribe it so that it's usable on my website, I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. The *code snippet* option is for providing a runnable demo.. For providing a piece of code use the *code sample* option instead... Your js alone is not sufficient for a demo so I'm converting the code snippet to code sample...

Comment: Or provide a JSfiddle, which is better.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Example:

```
$('#element_after_header').waypoint(function(direction){
     if(direction=='up'){
       $('header').show();
     }else{
       $('header').hide();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Timer is not needed to achieve the effect. You can try this...

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var header_height = 200;
    var current_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (current_scroll > header_height) {
            $('.cs_mega_menu').slideUp(1000); 
    }
    else{
            $('.cs_mega_menu').slideDown(1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your support. I've found a code here in stackoverflow that does exactly what I was looking for:

```
    $(function(){
    var lastScrollTop = 0, delta = 5;
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
       var st = $(this).scrollTop();
       if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
          return;
       if (st > lastScrollTop){
           // downscroll code
           $('.cs_mega_menu').slideUp('230');
       } else {
          // upscroll code
          $('.cs_mega_menu').slideDown('230');
       }
       lastScrollTop = st;
    });
});
```

Now I'm just struggling with making it appear on hover, but that's a different story.